# Error in Web Scraping using Python BeautifulSoup : Extracting content from github profile

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is python code for web scraping content from github repositories using BeautifulSoup library. I am facing error:

> "NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'"

in this simple code. I am facing error in 2 lines which is commented in the code.

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import csv 

URL = "https://github.com/DURGESHBARWAL?tab=repositories"
r = requests.get(URL) 

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser') 

repos = []
table = soup.find('ul', attrs = {'data-filterable-for':'your-repos-filter'}) 

for row in table.find_all('li', attrs = {'itemprop':'owns'}): 
    repo = {}
    repo['name'] = row.find('div').find('h3').a.text
    #First Error Position
        repo['desc'] = row.find('div').p.text
        #Second Error Postion
    repo['lang'] = row.find('div', attrs = {'class':'f6 text-gray mt-2'}).find('span', attrs = {'class':'mr-3'}).text
    repos.append(repo) 

filename = 'extract.csv'
with open(filename, 'w') as f: 
    w = csv.DictWriter(f,['name','desc','lang'])
    w.writeheader() 
    for repo in repos: 
        w.writerow(repo)
```

**OUTPUT**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "webscrapping.py", line 16,
>   in 
>       repo['desc'] = row.find('div').p.text AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: You should breakdown your code to understand what happens. Clearly row.find('div').p (line 16) returns a void object (NoneType) and therefore an instance of NoneType having no attributes you get an exception saying that NoneType has no attribute

Comment: Can you check whether your `div` tag contains a `p` tag? If yes, try `row.find('div' ).find('p' ).text()`

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is when you are finding elements via BeautifulSoup, it's acting like a `dict.get()` call. When you go to `find` elements, it `get`s them from the element tree. If it can't find one, rather than raising an `Exception`, it returns `None`. `None` doesn't have the attributes that an `Element` will have, like `text`, `attr`, etc. So when you make an `Element.text` call with no `try/except` or without verifying type, you are taking a gamble that the element will *always* be there.

I'd probably just keep the elements that are giving you issues in a temp variable first, that way you can type check. Either that or implement `try/except`

## Type Checking

```
for row in table.find_all('li', attrs = {'itemprop':'owns'}): 
    repo = {}
    repo['name'] = row.find('div').find('h3').a.text


    p = row.find('div').p
    if p is not None:
        repo['desc'] = p.text
    else:
        repo['desc'] = None

    lang = row.find('div', attrs = {'class':'f6 text-gray mt-2'}).find('span', attrs = {'class':'mr-3'})

    if lang is not None
        # Do something to pass here
        repo['lang'] = lang.text
    else:
        repo['lang'] = None
    repos.append(repo)
```

## try/except

```
for row in table.find_all('li', attrs = {'itemprop':'owns'}): 
    repo = {}
    repo['name'] = row.find('div').find('h3').a.text
    #First Error Position
    try:
        repo['desc'] = row.find('div').p.text
    except TypeError:
        repo['desc'] = None
        #Second Error Postion
    try:
        repo['lang'] = row.find('div', attrs = {'class':'f6 text-gray mt-2'}).find('span', attrs = {'class':'mr-3'}).text
    except TypeError:
         repo['lang'] = None
    repos.append(repo)
```

I would tend towards try/except, personally, because it is a bit more succinct and exception catching is a good practice for robustness of your program

Answer (score 0):

Your `find` calls are inaccurate and chained, so when you attempt to find a `<div>` tag that has no `p` child, you get `None`, but you proceed to call the attribute `.text` on `None`, which crashes your program with an `AttributeError`.

Try the following set of `.find` calls, which use the `itemProp` attributes you're after and uses a `try-except` block to null coalesce any missing fields:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import csv 

URL = "https://github.com/DURGESHBARWAL?tab=repositories"
r = requests.get(URL) 

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser') 

repos = []
table = soup.find('ul', attrs = {'data-filterable-for': 'your-repos-filter'}) 

for row in table.find_all('li', {'itemprop': 'owns'}): 
    repo = {
        'name': row.find('a', {'itemprop' : 'name codeRepository'}),
        'desc': row.find('p', {'itemprop' : 'description'}),
        'lang': row.find('span', {'itemprop' : 'programmingLanguage'})
    }

    for k, v in repo.items():
        try: 
            repo[k] = v.text.strip()
        except AttributeError: pass

    repos.append(repo)

filename = 'extract.csv'
with open(filename, 'w') as f: 
    w = csv.DictWriter(f,['name','desc','lang'])
    w.writeheader() 
    for repo in repos: 
        w.writerow(repo)
```

Debug output (in addition to written CSV):

```
[   {   'desc': 'This a Django-Python Powered a simple functionality based '
                'Bot application',
        'lang': 'Python',
        'name': 'Sandesh'},
    {'desc': None, 'lang': 'Jupyter Notebook', 'name': 'python_notes'},
    {   'desc': 'Installing DSpace using docker',
        'lang': 'Java',
        'name': 'DSpace-Docker-Installation-1'},
    {   'desc': 'This Repo Contains the DSpace Installation Steps',
        'lang': None,
        'name': 'DSpace-Installation'},
    {   'desc': '(Official) The DSpace digital asset management system that '
                'powers your Institutional Repository',
        'lang': 'Java',
        'name': 'DSpace'},
    {   'desc': 'This Repo contain the DSpace installation steps with '
                'docker.',
        'lang': None,
        'name': 'DSpace-Docker-Installation'},
    {   'desc': 'This Repository contain the Intermediate system for the '
                'Collaboration and DSpace System',
        'lang': 'Python',
        'name': 'Community-OER-Repository'},
    {   'desc': 'A class website to share the knowledge and expanding the '
                'productivity through digital communication.',
        'lang': 'PHP',
        'name': 'class-website'},
    {   'desc': 'This is a POC for the Voting System. It is a precise '
                'design and implementation of Voting System based on the '
                'features of Blockchain which has the potential to '
                'substitute the traditional e-ballet/EVM system for voting '
                'purpose.',
        'lang': 'Python',
        'name': 'Blockchain-Based-Ballot-System'},
    {   'desc': 'It is a short describtion of Modern Django',
        'lang': 'Python',
        'name': 'modern-django'},
    {   'desc': 'It is just for the sample work.',
        'lang': 'HTML',
        'name': 'Task'},
    {   'desc': 'This Repo contain the sorting algorithms in C,predefiend '
                'function of C, C++ and Java',
        'lang': 'C',
        'name': 'Sorting_Algos_Predefined_functions'},
    {   'desc': 'It is a arduino program, for monitor the temperature and '
                'humidity from sensor DHT11.',
        'lang': 'C++',
        'name': 'DHT_11_Arduino'},
    {   'desc': "This is a registration from,which collect data from user's "
                'desktop and put into database after validation.',
        'lang': 'PHP',
        'name': 'Registration_Form'},
    {   'desc': 'It is a dynamic multi-part data driven search engine in '
                'PHP & MySQL from absolutely scratch for the website.',
        'lang': 'PHP',
        'name': 'search_engine'},
    {   'desc': 'It is just for learning github.',
        'lang': None,
        'name': 'Hello_world'}]
```

Comment: Glad to hear. Feel free to upvote or accept if the answer helped solve the problem.